# Predicate logic - Quantifier

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I’m a little bit stuck here, I really don’t know which variables belongs to which quantifier and how I can simplify that.

$$
\forall x \forall y \left[
P(x,y) \land \neg \forall x \exists y P(x,y)
\right]
$$

Can you give me a poke in the right direction?

Comment: I think your predicate is equivalent to $$
\forall x
\forall y
\left[
P(x,y)
\land
\neg
\forall a
\exists b
P(a,b)
\right]
$$
perhaps this helps

Comment: It does, thanks!